# Is it possible to do Load testing on a Simulator?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, jmeter-5.0

I am currently working on a Banking application in which there is a Simulator application where manual test is being done by setting up data on the simulator and triggering it to check whether it is getting updated on the backend. Based on the test case, they are changing the parameter and testing this. I need to know if Load testing can be done for this simulator. Since there is no user directly involved and no API or no request is going through, can Load testing be done on this? If yes, is there a way to do it using Jmeter?

Answer (score 2):

If the "Simulator" (whatever it is) is capable of sending data to the backend theoretically it should be possible to use JMeter to simulate "simulator"'s network footprint.

You need to analyze what is happening on a network level when the "Simulator" talks to the backend, one of the options is using a [network sniffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Once you know which [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols)(s) is (are) in scope you should be able to choose appropriate JMeter [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) to mimic "simulator"'s traffic.

If you're in luck and "Simulator" uses [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol for communicating with the backend you will even be able to record the traffic using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). See [How to Do Desktop Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/desktop-performance-testing) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to perform Load testing using Simulator. We can record and develop PVT scripts using simulator and execute in Controller.

Comment: What does PVT/Controller mean in this context? As a java programmer for years I cannot understand these 2 terms in this question.

Answer (score 0):

PVT controller actually simulated virtual users and through this we can perform load or pvt test to mimic realistic scenario.
We should know simulator which we wanted here to automate is using which protocol and based on that we can generate pvt script and run load test.